# How to write complex conditional validation in JSON schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

Below is the sample JSON schema.
I need to implement this validation -

If `property1` has a value of "`abc`" and `property2`  has "`abc111`" in the list of provided values, then `subProperty1` is mandatory inside `property3`

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "property1": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "property2": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "property3": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "subProperty1": {
          ...
        },
        "subProperty2": {
          ...
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to implement it using this JSON -

```
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "property1": {
        "const": "abc"
      },
      "property2": {
        "contains": {
          "properties": {
            "items": {
              "const": "abc111"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "dependentSchemas": {
      "property1": {
        "required": [ "property3" ],
        "message": "Error - Missing property3 with subProperty1",
        "properties": {
          "property3": {
            "required": [ "subProperty1" ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But this doesnt work as expected. Could someone please help me fix the conditional logic?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without knowing in what way things aren't working as expected. But you may be missing a `required` keyword in your `if` clause -- in order to ensure that `property1` really is present. (The `properties` keyword evaluates to true if the property isn't present at all.) Then you would also need a `required: ["property3"]` in your `then` clause.

Also, you don't need `dependentSchemas` at all -- you are adding a dependency on property1, but that's already in the `if` clause so it's redundant.